# How can I update an exiting column on Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, summernote

I have a page where I am able to add content using a summernote.But when I update the content there are no changes.

**Here is my StoreController.**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $detail=$request->content;
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHtml($detail, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
    $images = $dom->getelementsbytagname('img');
    foreach($images as $k => $img){
        $data = $img->getattribute('src');
        list($type, $data) = explode(';', $data);
        list(, $data)      = explode(',', $data);
        $data = base64_decode($data);
        $image_name= time().$k.'.png';
        $path = public_path('uploads') .'/'. $image_name;

        file_put_contents($path, $data);

        $img->removeattribute('src');
        $img->setattribute('src', 'uploads'.'/'.$image_name);
    }

    $detail = $dom->savehtml();
    $abouts = new about;
    $abouts->content = $detail;
    $abouts->save();
    return view('admin.about',compact('abouts'));
}
```

**Here is my UpdateController**

```
    public function update(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->isMethod('POST')){

            //in this section all code are same as like as my store controller
            
            $abouts->update();
            return view('admin.about',compact('abouts'));
        }

    }
```

Any ideas on how I could fix this?

Comment: you are creating new instance of about

Comment: if that's correct to create new instance in the update method of controller then you should check the about model and make sure it has $fillable array available.

Comment: Yes, it has protected $fillable =['content'];

Comment: when you did dd($detail), is there any data?

Comment: Please do dd() and check what's going on when you try to store the data, you'll know exactly

Comment: usually the update method has "PUT" request method

Comment: Can you show your form and route?

Comment: [my from](https://jsbin.com/kovavayime/edit?html)

here you can see my form.
**Routes are**

Route::post('/Admin/about', 'AboutController@store')->name('editAbout');
Route::get('/Admin/edit/about', 'AboutController@edit');
Route::post('/Admin/edit/about', 'AboutController@update')->name('updateAbout');

@Sobir

Comment: Do you have any other forms that are not working properly? Your route post location might be wrong, I mean check id you really are sending the data to Route::post(‘/Admin/about’). Do a dd($request) after that to see what’s being send.

Comment: Routes are ok @VladimirB.

Comment: Check `public function update(Request $request) { dd($request); }` in `UpdateController`

Answer (score 0):

In your Store function you have used this `$abouts = new about;`
Are you doing the same in update functions? then it will be a new instance.

Adding Validations may help you know the reason why it's not getting updated.

`\Log::debug('message');` can also be useful if you still don't get the issue after putting validations.

```
public function update($id, Request $request)
{
    //you can pass $id of the record which you want to update or even pass it along with the other request parameters.
    $task = Task::findOrFail($id);

    //validate the request( would suggest to do the same in your store function too. )
    $this->validate($request, [
        'title' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required'
    ]);

    $input = $request->all();

    $task->fill($input)->save();

    Session::flash('flash_message', 'Task successfully added!');

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The best solution is to test it first if you are getting data in the request or not using `dd()` method. OR

you can try this:

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    if($request->isMethod('PUT')){

        //in this section all code are same as like as my store controller
        
        $abouts->update();
        return view('admin.about',compact('abouts'));
    }

}
```

or you can remove that if condition and try

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    

        //in this section all code are same as like as my store controller
        
        $abouts->update();
        return view('admin.about',compact('abouts'));
    

}
```

Comment: I also try this method @Naveed Ali